# How do DHT22 and gpio's work?

Tags: c++, linux, embedded, sensors

I just got myself a sensor DHT22 for temperature and humidity and I have some doubts:
- Is this device only usable with arduino or Rpi?
- If the answer is No, how does it work with the GPIO? As far as I understand, gpio has2 options: -Direcion (in or out) and Value (0 or 1). So according to this, I was checking a lot of examples for arduino and Rpi on how to use this devices, and all are attached to gpio's port. So how is this working? Does c/c++ has bigger capacity to handle this readings?
- If the sensor can be used with more devices, is there any linux standard library/code to handle this device?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DHT22 is, as you described, made to work over GPIO pins. That means that any device with GPIO can use it.

About the libraries. There are two major libraries for communicating via GPIO written, one for C++ and one for Python. That means that any device that has GPIO and can run Python or C++ can use your DHT22.

**What about no C++, Python, Java... based libraries?** Well, there is **no** *Linux standard library* for communicating over GPIO. Of course, if you are eager to learn and explore, you can write a library in Assembly or Bash, which would be as close to LSL as you can get. By doing that you can natively communicate over GPIO from Linux shell without any other programming language. If you are interested in Bash, take a look at [this](http://raspberrypi-aa.github.io/session2/bash.html).

**How does Linux know the temperature and humidity when it can only read 0s and 1s?** Consider two things:

1. How does computer store number *32*? The computer only knows *0*'s and *1*'s so he needs to convert *32* to binary. What is *32 = 2^6* in decimal, is *100000* in binary.
2. How does computer read temperature and humidity? When you execute a function like

   ```
   get_temperature()
   ```

   which requests temperature from DHT22, what actually happens is that your computer sends signal to DHT22 (it "writes" to DHT22 over GPIO through IN on DHT22, which is the same as OUT on computer). Then the DHT22 senses the temperature and "sends" data back. **How does it send it?** It creates a sequence of electric charges through GPIO (GPIO IN on computer and GPIO OUT on DHT22). In our case, if temperature is *32*, then it sends the next sequence: *1-0-0-0-0-0*. The computer reads the sequence and when you try to print it to screen it converts it into decimal.

Hope I got myself clear and this is what you wanted.

In this [link](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_DHT/blob/master/source/Raspberry_Pi_2/pi_2_dht_read.c) you find a C code for reading DHT22 temperature and humidity if that is what you want. Please let me know what you want to do in general (read temp. and hum. via library, write new library for communicating over GPIO, write new library in another language for DHT22...).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What about the question about gpio functioning? why on linux I can only get values 0 or 1 and with c++ or python i can read for example the temperature of humidity in this case?

Comment: I will edit in answer to complete it, thanks for reminding me I missed something...

Comment: Thanks for the link. Here is where my problem comes, I connect the DHT22 to my gpio and then I do as on the link you send me, the only thing i get is 0. I expected to get periodically some values, but no. I dont understand this, could be may be that my sensor is not properly connected?

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty neat about how it work. What I want to do? I have a board, (Rpi style) and I just want to read temp and humidity for the sensor, but all the libraries I found are specific for arduino/Rpi.

Comment: What board exactly do you have and I assume it is running Linux? Debian-like? Since you said it's RPi-like, I think the designers made it possible to run everything that can be run on RPi on your own board...

Comment: It's barely known, I have tools to crosscompile external libs. It's running basic linux, busybox. It supports c/c++ tho, but nothing else :P

Comment: Then take a look at [WiringPi](http://wiringpi.com/), a C, C++ and BASIC compatible library. I really think that people that made your board wanted to imitate RPi's functionality which means you can use any library that *was meant for RPi* on your board.

Comment: Great, thanks mate,this was really helpfull. I'll check it as good answer ;) Just one more thing, the lib from github that you linked on main post could be also usable, right? I mean, i wouldnt need the wiringpi.

Comment: No problemo, amigo! Haven't done anything with my RPi for so long that it was really fun answering you because it got me back in that *little engineer* mood :) Thanks for checking and upvoting! :P