# Where to find device-tree?

Tags: linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, embedded

Coming form [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46036474/how-do-dht22-and-gpios-work/46036618?noredirect=1#comment79034731_46036618) question yesterday, I decided to port [this](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_DHT/blob/master/source/Raspberry_Pi_2/pi_2_dht_read.c) library to my board. I was aware that I needed to change something, so I compiled the library, call it on a small program and see what happens. The 1st problem is here:

```
    // Check for GPIO and peripheral addresses from device tree.
    // Adapted from code in the RPi.GPIO library at:
    //   http://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/
    FILE *fp = fopen("/proc/device-tree/soc/ranges", "rb");
    if (fp == NULL) {
      return MMIO_ERROR_OFFSET;
    }
```

This lib is aimed for Rpi, os the structure of the system on my board is not the same. So I was wondering if somebody could tell me where I could find this file or how it looks like so I can find it by my self in order to proceed the job.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you could download a Raspbian OS and look into the file.

Comment: *"where I could find this file..."* -- That *"file"* exists only in the special procfs filesystem, and that **/proc/device-tree/** subdirectory is derived from the board's Device Tree blob.  In DT source code that **ranges** *"file"* exists as only one line within a file (e.g. **arch/arm/boot/dts/bcm2835.dtsi**).  Your board (which you neglect to provide any details) would only use DT if it had a PPC or ARM SoC, and even then the structure of the DT could be different from this Broadcom example.

Comment: Doing such driver in user space seems not the best idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't necessarily want that "file" (or more precisely /proc node).

The code this is found in is setting up to do direct **memory mapped I/O** using what appears to be a pi-specific gpio-flavored version of the `/dev/mem` type of device driver for exposing hardware special function registers to userspace.

To port this to your board, you would need to first determine if there is a `/dev/mem` or similar capability in your kernel which you can activate.  Then you would need to determine the appropriate I/O registers for GPIO pins.  The pi-specific code is reading the Device Tree to figure this out, but there are other ways, for example you can manually read the programmer's manual of the SoC on which you are running.

Another approach you can consider is adding some small microcontroller (or yes, barebones ***duino) to the system, and using that to collect information from various sensors and peripherals.  This can then be forwarded to the SoC over a UART link, or queried out via I2C or similar - add a small amount of cost and some degree of bottleneck, but also means that the software on the SoC then becomes very portable - to a different comparable chip, or perhaps even to run on a desktop PC during development.

Comment: I see, so I could actually use the same pi code but changing the registers for the Gpio's, that would work for my device, right?

Comment: That would depend on the capabilities of your device, which you've rather oddly avoided identifying.